# Golang: Mock an interface method before Init method is called

Tags: go, go-testing, gomock

How can I mock something that gets called in a package `init()` method?

For example:

**main.go**

```
var myService MyService = myservicepkg.New()

func init(){
   response := myService.get()
}

func otherMethod(){
   //do something
}
```

**maintest.go**

```
func Test_otherMethod(){
  ctrl := NewController(t)
  defer ctrl.Finish()
  myServiceMock = myservicepkg.NewMock(myService)

  myServiceMock.EXPECT().get().return("success")
}
```

The problem is that `init()` is called before the service is replaced by the mock.

Comment: You cannot. Redesign.

Comment: Tiago's right: the problem stems from your abuse of mutable global state. If, instead of declaring `myService` as a package-level variable, you store a `MyService` value in a field of some custom struct type, testability will markedly improve.

Answer (score 1):

This is the issue of work with a mutable global state.

My advice is to add a *flag* to not run this on certain conditions or expose a private function that can recover/update this global variable in an *internal* test.

This reflects your design: if it is complicate to test, perhaps you should refactor.

Create an object Application with a field Service, created on the constructor/builder/factory will be easier to test.

The usage of init is very delicate. Besides register a driver into sql packages, I never use it (perhaps to handle flags).

Perhaps you can add more OO to your design

Answer (score 0):

You will need to call the `otherMethod()` inside `init()`. It can't be called before `init()` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, you can prevent the init code from being executed in your test and test the method in isolation like this:

```
func init(){
  if len(os.Args) > 0 && strings.HasSuffix(os.Args[0], ".test") {
    log.Printf("skipping jwt.init() for testing")
  } else if len(os.Args) > 1 && strings.HasSuffix(os.Args[1], "-test.run") {
    log.Printf("skipping jwt.init() for testing")
  } else { 
    response := myService.get()
  }
}
```

This will prevent the init service calls from being called.